# Implement Room with RxJava and Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2, android-room, clean-architecture

I am trying to use Room with RxJava and Retrofit, Before You recommend use a component arch (In this opportunity is not possible, the project is in and 50% and Just need to continue with the arch clean).

So the **problem** is this. I have a web service that returns a **POJO**. Something like this:

```
{
 "success":"true",
 "message":"message",
 "data":{[
   "id":"id",
   "name":"name",
   "lname":"lname",
 ]} 
}
```

POJO is more complex but for the example is ok with this. I need to do that since my view make query to invoke data from room, but if there is not data in my db call my web services,the reponse of my web services transform to entity and save in my db (room) and after return a list of data to my view.

I am using clean arch. I appreciate anyhelp with this. Again not trying to use

**data layout**

- database
- network
- repository

**domain**

- interactor
- callbacks

**presentation**

- presenter
- view

> POJO API response

```
{
 "success":"true",
 "message":"message",
 "data":{[
   "id":"id",
   "name":"name",
   "address":"address",
   "phone":"phone",
 ]} 
}
```

> My db entity

```
@Entity(tableName = "clients")
    public class clients {

    String id;
    String name;
    String address;
    String phone;
    String status;


    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

> My dao for room

```
@Dao
public interface ClientsDao {

     @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
     void saveAll(List<Clients> clients);

     @Query("SELECT * FROM Clients")
     Flowable<List<Clients>> listClients();

}
```

> RxJava help class

```
public class RxHelper {
private static final String TAG = RxHelper.class.getName();

@NonNull
public static <T>Observable<T> getObserbable(@NonNull final Call<T> reponse){

    return Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<T>() {
        @Override
        public void subscribe(final ObservableEmitter<T> emitter) throws Exception {

            reponse.enqueue(new Callback<T>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response) {

                    if (!emitter.isDisposed()) {
                        emitter.onNext(response.body());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<T> call, Throwable t) {
                    if (!emitter.isDisposed()) {
                        emitter.onError(t);
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    });

}
}
```

> My ClientsRepoFactory

```
public Observable<ResponseClients> getApiClients(){
        String token = preferences.getValue(SDConstants.token);
        return RxHelper.getObserbable(apiNetwork.getClients(token));
}
```

> My ClientsRepo

```
@Override
public Observable<ResponseClients> listClients() {
    return factory.listClients();
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure why clean architecture, i.e. your implementation which just lists your approach, has got to do with using 3 libraries together - Google brings up plenty of tutorials on how to use them together - implement it however you want.

Comment: Hi Mark, The project is pretty bigger, so I just need to help with this feature.my first options were read official documentation, however, I didn't find the best way to implements room + rxjava + retrofit together (for this case) in particular

Comment: As you've not posted any code (have you attempted anything?) any answers will be based on assumptions, which probably won't provide adequate answer. You've provided very high level overview of your application, but you're faced with an implementation detail/problem - using 3 libraries together - you see how your question content doesn't really correlate to your question title.

Comment: you can use A relatively database like objectbox  or realm that These are faster and easy query for  complex Json structure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i dont work with room but familiar with rxjava you can design your repository like that

your room interfac

```
@Query(“SELECT * FROM Users WHERE id = :userId”)
Single<User> getUserById(String userId);
```

**when use :**
**Maybe**  When there is no user in the database and the query returns no rows, Maybe will complete.

**Flowable** Every time the user data is updated, the Flowable object will emit automatically, allowing you to update the UI based on the latest dat

**Single** When there is no user in the database and the query returns no rows, Single will trigger onError(EmptyResultSetException.class)

read more about Room and  RxJava  this [link](https://medium.com/google-developers/room-rxjava-acb0cd4f3757)

to achieve " if there is not data in db call  web services " create your repository methode like that

```
public Single<User> getUserById(String userId){
 return  db.getUserById(userId)
              /// if there is no user in the database get data from api
             .onErrorResumeNext(api.getUserById(userId)
              .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
              //check your request
              .filter(statusPojo::getStatus)
               // save data to room
              .switchMap(data -> {
              //sava data to db
              return Observable.just(data)
              })
           );

}
```

finally call repository method from interactor to  passed obsrevable to interactor then to presentation layout

more detail : you can inject Api and DB to your repository

**update_Answer** for reactive db 
if you want get last update on UI just do it :

your room interface:

```
@Query(“SELECT * FROM Users WHERE id = :userId”)
Flowable<User> getUserById(String userId);
```

repository :

```
   @Override
public Flowable<User> getUser(int id) {
    getUserFromNet(id);
         //first emit cache data in db and after request complete   emit last update from net 
        return db.getUserById(id);

 }


 private Flowable<User> getUserFromNet(int id){
      api.getUserById(userId)
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
          .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
          //check your request
          .filter(statusPojo::getStatus)
           // save data to room
          .subscribe(new DisposableObserver<User>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(User user) {
                     // save data to room
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Timber.e(e);
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {


                }
            });
}
```

**update_Answer2** for reactive db and " if there is not data in db call web services "
according this [issue](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/84) is better use return a `Flowable <List<T>>`

and check list size instead of `Flowable<T>` white `swichIfEmpity` because if don't any user in db `Flowable<T>` do'nt call `onNext()` and don't emite `FlowableEmpity();`

```
private Flowable<List<User>>  getUser(int id){
       return db.getUserById(id).
         /// if there is no user in the database get data from 
           .flatMp(userList-> 
           if(userList.size==0)
          api.getUserById(userId)
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
          //check your request
          .filter(statusPojo::getStatus)
           // save data to room
          .subscribe(new DisposableObserver<User>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(User user) {
                     // save data to room
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Timber.e(e);
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {


                }
            });
                return Flowable.just(data)
                );
}
```

**Kotlin way** with  retrofit , paging (pagingRX androidx) and room  :

room Dao:

```
@Dao
abstract class UserDao   {

@Query("SELECT * FROM users ")
abstract fun findAll(): DataSource.Factory<Int, User>
}
```

Repository:

```
private fun getFromDB(pageSize:Int): Flowable<PagedList<User>> {
    return RxPagedListBuilder(userDao.findAll(), pageSize)
        .buildFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST)
}


private fun getApi(page: Int,pageSize: Int): Disposable {
    return api.getUserList("token", page = page,perPage = pageSize)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe { t1: List<User>?, t2: Throwable? ->
            t1?.let {
                if (it.isNotEmpty())
                    userDao.insert(it)
            }
        }
}

override fun  findAll(page: Int ,pageSize:Int ): 
Flowable<PagedList<User>> {
    return getFromDB(pageSize).doOnSubscribe { getApi(page,pageSize) }
}
```

Comment: Hi Amin, thnks so much for yous answer, Just have a dude what about there is data but need to update data, It's possible with RxJava make two queries to same time (API call and db query) and response api call update db, and after that db response to my interactor?

Comment: Hi Amin, thnaks so much for your answer, Just I have a doubt, What about if there is data but need to update data, It's possible with RxJava make two queries to same time (API call and db query) and response api call update db, and after that db response to my interactor?

Comment: U can use Flowable  to get data and in flatmap update db , you get last value in db after update value in flatmap ,  Flowable run query again and emit updated values

Comment: Hi Amin, tahnks for yous answer, when there is not data in DB, How get event with Flowable, I read that when there is not data will not emit, neither onNext, nor onError. how get the event to throw call to my api?

Comment: Hi Amin, I appreciate a lot your help, this solve my problem with update database before to return data, but think is not a good idea always call a API to update, in this case just need to update when database is empty. I am reading that maybe is possible with "switchIfEmpty" do hear about it?

Comment: maybe it's Better choice for u ,test it . i don't khnow what you want but for ''in this case just need to update when database is empty.'' i recommend u my first solution.

Comment: I will use it, Thanks Amin!

Comment: @user1153174 hi i update my  answer  check it again ;)